# Can I install a WYSIWYG editor to my website?

Tags: wysiwyg

I've build my own website from scratch as I needed it to be built especially for my business. That went well so far, but now I want to make the "articles engine".(store them in a database, display based on name etc) and I was wondering if there is a way to install an editor, cause that would make my editing job so much easier. I've tried looking it up but all I found was CMS oriented plugins. Those could work, but editing them would most likely take soo long. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: download the wysiwyg editor of your choice usually they will come with some demo.html which if you open up in your text editor you will see how it is applied to the page, some understanding of [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) would be handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `CKEditor` (aka:`FCKEditor`) editor for many years.

http://ckeditor.com/

There are many alternatives but my advice is this.